# throw error() doesn't redirect to error page in Sveltekit

Tags: error-handling, svelte, sveltekit, progressive-enhancement

So i have a form that uses `use:enhance` and i check if there is an error in the result to throw an error.

But whn I throw the error it shows in the console, but it doesn't redirect to my `+error.svelte` page

Here's my `use:enhance` code :

```
use:enhance={() => {
        //disabling form and button
        formDisabled = true;

        return async ({ result }) => {
          //@ts-ignore
          if (result.type === "success" && result.data.success === true) {
            //reactivating the form
            formDisabled = false;
          } else {
            throw error(500, {
              message: "Internal Server Error",
            });
          }
        };
      }}
```

I also tried to put the throw error in the `onMount()` to see if it would redirect me if it is at the start but it still doesn't :/

I really have no idea because in the docs it says that `throw error()` should redirect and I never had a problem with it before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors only really work during SSR and in server code like the `load` function. The problem presumably is, that the code running on the client does not run in a context where all errors can be easily handled.

`enhance` probably *could* implement the logic since it is provided by SvelteKit but from your observations it looks like that is not the case.

There are various potential workarounds:

- Throw errors earlier, on the server during the action

  - If a result handle function is returned by `enhance`, you need to use `update` or `applyAction` to handle errors (see [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-customising-use-enhance))
- Use [validation error](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#anatomy-of-an-action-validation-errors) handling instead, which is the intended way of handling issues with form actions.

  - return a `fail`
  - use `form` property and conditionally show some error content directly
- (Redirect to an error page using `goto`, this is not really recommended as the user will be stuck on the error page on refresh)

---

Possibly not a good idea, but `applyAction` can also be used in non-action contexts, e.g.:

```js
onMount(() => {
    applyAction({ type: 'error', error: { message: 'Test error' } });
});
```

Comment: I also tried to throw the error in my `+page.server.ts` but it still doesn't redirect, I get the error in the console but that's all. And the problem with returning a `fail` is that the thing that can go wrong is not in the form, it is a mail submission, so it isn't the user fault.

Comment: If you return a result handle function in `enhance`, the default logic will no longer happen automatically so the thrown error is not handled. You can e.g. call the supplied `update` function or call `applyAction` on the `result`, this is documented [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-customising-use-enhance).

Comment: (Actually you can (ab)use `applyAction` to show errors anywhere.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for these precious comments, I used the `update` function and now it redirects perfectly :)

Comment: You are welcome, if that sufficiently answered the question, you could accept the answer (I updated it earlier to include the info from the comments).